# Passing Gridview values to New WebPage - Cannot Edit Values in New WebPage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Basic to design a web application.

I have a gridview with a button on each row that opens a new webpage and fills in the fields with values from the row button clicked.  Works fine.  The problem is - I want the user to be able to edit the fields on the new webpage - no luck.  Change it, and it changes back to value from gridview.  How can these fields become editable?  I was thinking it may be a TextChanged event but I can't get it to work.

Here's part of my code. Thanks in advance!

```
ASPX
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="TimeOffNoRequestEdit.aspx.vb" Inherits="timework.TimeOffNoRequestEdit" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolkitScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
     style="color: #990033; font-weight: 700"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
     style="color: #000099; font-weight: 700"></asp:Label>
<br />
<label>Employee Name:</label><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" 
     style="margin-left: 0px; font-size: medium; font-weight: 700;" 
     Width="150px" Height="22px" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="129px" 
     AutoPostBack="True" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<hr align="left" style="width: 791px; margin-left: 0px" />
<label>Date Requested:</label><asp:TextBox ID="DateRequested" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px; font-size: medium; font-weight: 500;" 
     Width="150px" Height="22px" AutoPostBack="True" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<p />
<label>Begin Date Off:</label><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 10px; font-size: medium; font-weight: 500;" 
     Width="150px" Height="22px" AutoPostBack="True" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<label>&nbsp; End Date Off:</label><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="margin-left: 15px; font-size: medium; font-weight: 500;" 
     Width="150px" Height="22px" AutoPostBack="True" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
<p />
<label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; All Day?</label>&nbsp;<asp:CheckBox ID=Checkbox1 runat="server" />
<br />
<label>Begin Time Off:</label>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" style="margin-left: 12px; font-size: medium; font-weight: 500;" 
     Width="150px" Height="22px" AutoPostBack="True" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
<br /> 
<label>&nbsp;&nbsp; End Time Off:</label>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" 
     runat="server" style="margin-left: 12px; font-size: medium; font-weight: 500;" 
     Width="148px" Height="22px" AutoPostBack="True" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
<label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Reason:<asp:TextBox 
     ID="TextBox5" runat="server" style="margin-left:10px; font-size: medium; font-weight: 500;" 
     Width="150px" Height="22px" AutoPostBack="True" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox></label>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" />

</asp:Content>

Visual Basic    

   Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim windowsLoginName As System.String = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name   'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

    Dim split As String() = Nothing
    Dim vname As String

    Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=janetdev;Initial Catalog=TimeSQL;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password")
    Dim cmd, cmd1, cmd2 As New SqlCommand
    Dim returnValue, returnValue1, returnValue2 As Object
    Dim dt As Date = Today

    'Get network login name (name only)
    split = windowsLoginName.Split("\".ToCharArray)
    vname = split(1)

    'Get firstname from tblEmployees that matches login name
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FirstName FROM tblEmployees where login = '" & vname & "'"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection

    'Get lastname from tblEmployees that matches login name
    cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT LastName FROM tblEmployees where login = '" & vname & "'"
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd1.Connection = sqlConnection

    'Get employeeid from tblEmployees that matches login name 
    cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM tblEmployees where login = '" & vname & "'"
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd2.Connection = sqlConnection

    sqlConnection.Open()

    'firstname
    returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

    'lastname
    returnValue1 = cmd1.ExecuteScalar()

    'employeeid
    returnValue2 = cmd2.ExecuteScalar()

    sqlConnection.Close()

    'display firstname and lastname on screen
    TextBox3.Text = returnValue & " " & returnValue1
    TextBox4.Text = returnValue2

    'display today's date
    DateRequested.Text = dt

    'Get value of other fields 

    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("BeginDateOff").ToString()) Then
        'Retrieving the BeginDateOff Value
        TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString("BeginDateOff").ToString()
    End If

    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("EndDateOff").ToString()) Then
        'Retrieving the EndDateOff Value
        TextBox2.Text = Request.QueryString("EndDateOff").ToString()
    End If

    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("BeginTimeOff").ToString()) Then
        'Retrieving the BeginTimeOff Value
        TextBox6.Text = Request.QueryString("BeginTimeOff").ToString()
    End If

    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("EndTimeOff").ToString()) Then
        'Retrieving the EndTimeOff Value
        TextBox7.Text = Request.QueryString("EndTimeOff").ToString()
    End If
    'Retrieving the All Day Value
    Checkbox1.Checked = Boolean.Parse(Request.QueryString("AllDay_YesNo"))

    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("Description").ToString()) Then
        'Retrieving the Description Value
        TextBox5.Text = Request.QueryString("Description").ToString()
    End If

    DateRequested.Focus()

End Sub
```

Comment: you can pass the values using `query string`

Comment: I did - it's in the visual basic code - scroll down.  It passes them to the new webpage, but doesn't let me edit them.

Comment: Nadeem - thanks for your quick response.  Do you see the vb code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `if(!PostBack)` before populating textboxes - otherwise you are rewriting them with original values on each postback.

**UPDATE:**

`Page_Load` runs on every postback, automatic (`AutoPostBack`) or manual (button click), and does so **after** textboxes receive new values, but **before** they are processed by the event handler.

So, short answer, just simply add `if(PostBack) return;` to the very top of your `Page_Load`.

And the long answer would be that you really need to know this by heart before doing anything else: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Even if AutoPostBack is set to True on all the fields?

Comment: Can you please give me code to do this?  All of a sudden I'm confused about the autopostback.  What I thought it did was not what I think it does now.  Thanks!

Comment: You are populating the fields from the database every single page load. You only need to populate them on the first page load so that you can read the values the user has inserted when the page does an autopostback. You're basically overriding the user's value every time the page goes to the server.

Comment: Thanks!  I put If Page.IsPostBack = True Then
            Return
        End If

Comment: Thanks!  It worked and I was very confused before you explained how the Page_Load and AutoPostBack works.  I'm a newbie and this is the first page I designed to edit.   I put the following at the top of Page Load and it worked.  If Page.IsPostBack = True Then Return   End If        The only problem I still have is that I have to click the Save button twice before it saves to the SQL database.  The first time it seems like it says yes I'll keep the changes, the second time, it saves to the database.  Should I put this in a new post?  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @user3033348 - you are quite welcome, this site has helped us all one time or another, just don't forget to accept the answer... and yes, you should make a new question for that other problem